# Is it only possible to analize the speed of Coulomb force field if it could possibly be slower in certain media?

Tags: forces, electric-fields, charge, speed-of-light, friction

Let say there is a media that slows down the speed of the Coulomb force field although we pressume that it is just 'c' or the speed of light no matter of the media of its propagation.Should then the hypothetical experiment on the picture give a difference between A and B or the time delay between the times of reaction of the charged body on a surface with friction coef. depending on the media between the charged sphere and the charged body.Ofcourse the motion of the body happens when the sphere is placed from distance of e.g. 1.1m to 1.0m from the body......

**Important edit**...As the media as being a dielectric increases the net force on the body a rope should be added to help the friction to prevent the body from movement(or better a magnet) so when this is balanced it should cause the body to start moving at the same distance of 1.0m from the sphere as there was only vacuum between them....

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as the speed of the Coulomb force. There is the speed of light, but that involves more than the Coulomb force.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of statics is that nothing changes and there is no speed. The Coulomb force is a phenomenon of electrostatics. Therefore, there cannot be such a thing as

> *"a media that slows down the speed of the Coulomb force field"*

The only thing that might come close to your vague feeling of matter changing the properties of the Coulomb field is a polarizable medium (actually all media are polarizable to some extent because matter is made up of nuclei and electrons, which are at least subject to van-der-Waals forces). Usually this is a dielectric, but conductors can also be polarized (even perfectly so).

The effect of polarization is roughly the same as a reduction of distance. This is used in capacitors for example, to increase capacitance without reducing actual plate distance.

Hence, if you put matter between the charge and the body suffering friction, the body will start moving already at a greater distance than without matter. Whether this distance is 1m, 1.1m or 1$\mu$m is, of course, a question of specific boundary conditions.

Comment: Let meet at a middle point...the material increases the distance of the body to start to move but this can be measured  and we can increase the resistance to movement by a rope that will be helping friction in preventing the body from movement and break just at the same distance of 1.0m so the body again starts to move at distance 1.0m.....